# Differences between JMS and CORBA?

Tags: jms, corba

I have just read about `CORBA` and `JMS`, they both seem to be used to implement 
***Broker Architecture/Pattern***.

I have few questions regarding them

1.The differences between them are still not clear to me, anybody please explain ?

2.Is CORBA is used in today's IT Solutions ? Or is it losing charm ?

3.Does JMS can replace every aspect of CORBA ?

Answer (score 5):

Ramon Gil Moreno is right in stating that

> JMS is the Java API that allows building applications to send and
>   receive messages. IBM MQ or ActiveMQ are samples of JMS vendors that
>   implements this API.

CORBA on the other hand is a specification that specifies how objects can interact with each other over a network across programming languages and run-time platforms.

The standard includes many APIs and infrastructure definitions (language bindings, marshalling, naming etc.), that are needed to support this. CORBA is still being used, and is Open Source as well as commercial (hard to find!)

Implementations exist, but I doubt if any of them covers 10% of the standard. Ramon's statement that CORBA is closer to RMI is a bit too simple - CORBA 2.4+ definitions include a CORBA Messaging definition that allows asynchronous and (reliable) queued communication.

Comment: Thanks for replying ! you are saying that CORBA is just an specification i.e. some set of standards which needs to be followed by messaging API's. Does JMS follows CORBA standards OR some other Standards ? It Would be great if you can update your answer OR provide answer according to each point asked so that it can be help full to all. :)

Answer (score 2):

CORBA, which is not hot nowdays, allows objects to be used remotely by different systems. It is more similar to RMI.

JMS is the Java API that allows building applications that send and receive messages. IBM MQ or ActiveMQ are samples of products that implements this API.

Comment: can you give some major differences among them, and also about the third point.

Comment: Apples and oranges. JMS does not replace every aspect of CORBA.